# ionic angular reactive form weird behaviour

Tags: forms, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, swiper.js, reactive

I have a form where I am using swiper js, so my form has two slides, on submit I am calling an api if it has error then I set usernamExists to true and then I want to go first slide of my form. It goes to the first slide but immediately goes back to the second slide where it has submit button. *Can anyone explain this and solve the issue*

```
for (let err of res.warnings) {
          if (err.item === 'username') {
            this.usernameExists = true;
            this.showWarning('danger', 'NEW_ACCOUNT.USERNAME_EXISTS');
            this.goPrev(); // send to the previous slide
          }
          if (err.item === 'email') {
            this.emailExists = true;
            this.showWarning('danger', 'NEW_ACCOUNT.EMAIL_EXISTS');
            this.goPrev(); // send to the previous slide I am making sure when slide index is zero it doesn't go to the negative
          }
        }
```

Now I fixed the issue using setTimeout , after 1 second delay I call this.goPrev();